# My esp32 print weird characters but I do anything

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port, communication, esp32

I only want to print simple text but it print unilimited weird character and never stop, (when I remove `Serial.print()` it continues to print weird characters).

This is the weird text that loop

```
-*⸮ql⸮7⸮$⸮
*!8P⸮⸮⸮V⸮)3 ⸮;⸮ 1⸮zY⸮b⸮ڔ!⸮⸮$q⸮,*⸮ı⸮N
⸮a!u⸮   1⸮zY⸮b⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮!⸮  1⸮zY⸮W(⸮⸮⸮xI⸮
,*-⸮l⸮N
⸮a!u⸮,*⸮⸮⸮nbb⸮H⸮⸮⸮⸮,*⸮⸮⸮nbb⸮H$⸮
    1⸮zY⸮b⸮ڔ!X⸮⸮⸮⸮,*⸮⸮⸮nbb⸮H$⸮
*!8Pt⸮
```

My code :

```
void setup() {

}

void loop() {

}
```

I hope you can help me, thanks :)

**UPDATE**

I completely removed `Serial.begin(9600)` and `Serial.print()` and I still have the problem O_o

Comment: Can you provide the code that result to this ?

Comment: @AdrienGivry sure

Comment: Please confirm: You have random crap coming out of the serial port whether you write to the port or not?

Comment: @user4581301 yes and as well when i remove all code

Comment: What about when you have no code at all? Might as well cross this one out early since it's a really easy test that could tell you that the hardware is <expletive deleted>ed. Once had a set f prototype boards that worked perfectly for almost exactly two weeks. Then mystery bugs galore. Turns out that's how long it took the glue used to hold the the surface mount chips in place for easier soldering to start conducting electricity.

Comment: @user4581301 I can't upload with blank file but just `loop()` and `setup()` do the same weird things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed the Flash memory speed to 40MHz instead of 80MHz

Answer (score 3):

If you are using arduino IDE ( you probably are ) you can try changing the baud rates. That's what happened to me in arduino some time ago

Comment: No it doesn't works, im at 921600 currently and this worked with my other esp32 last week

Comment: Have you tried setting your serial monitor to 115200? It's probably boot loader messages from your ESP at that speed.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was not the Baud rate. With both `Serial.begin(115200)` and the Serial monitor at 115200, some English chars were printed and most of them were unwanted/weird chars.

The issue in my case was that the ground pin of the ESP12F was not connected to the ground pin of the FTDI USB-to-Serial Converter. Once the ground pin was properly soldered on the PCB, every thing started working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the baud rate in the code and baud rate of the serial monitor are the same.

Example:
if your code has : Serial.begin(115200);

then change the baud rate of serial monitor to 115200, this can be done by accessing the baud as shown in the picture[image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXmgT.png)